# Break the Root password

Tags: password

How to reset the root password in ubuntu o.s ?

I have forgotten the root password  and tried to login in recovery mode but root password is asked.

Comment: While this is definitely a duplicate, note that the answer I gave here is not mentioned in the other Q&A.